# Is it secure to expose google shortener api key in code

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-url-shortener

I am using google shortener to generate a short URL, the long URL doesn't have any secret data, also the website is fully public.
there is any risk to put my API key in the source code for my app

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do that. If you put the API key in the source code, others will be able to call the Google API as you. From the [getting started doc](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started):

"By default, your registered project gets 1,000,000 requests per day for the URL Shortener API (see the Developers console for more details)."

This exposes you to a denial of service - if a malicious entity decides they don't like you, they can grab your source, make 1M short URL requests as you, and you will be unable to make the requests yourself.

Comment: There are a few "standard" ways to do this. One is to stand up your own server - so rather than calling Google APIs, they call your APIs which then call Google with your API key. This is useful if you're licensing users and want to control who can access and who can't. If you're doing open source, a good solution is to require each user to get their own Google API key, and provide a way for them to enter it. Then if they abuse it, it's not your problem - it's between them and Google.